# Measuring a voltage signal with a very steep ps risetimes

Tags: operational-amplifier, transient, high-speed

Lets say there is a black-box which gives a voltage output that evolves temporally from nV regime to few 100s of μV regime, in very  short time scales. i.e the signal evolves from nV to μV in ns with a steep rise-time.

If one needs to capture such a large variations without compromising on the time scales in question, what should be the considerations taken?

To have a numerical considerations of the scales in question, the signal bandwidth is roughly around 6 GHz and the slew rate is approximately 15.6 kV/μs. The rise time of signal is 60ps making the bandwidth from the approximation of 0.35/tr around 6GHz. The pulse swings to 1V with a rise time of 60ps, the rate of change of amplitude is 1V/60ps or around 16KV/μs in the maximum case with a pulse width of few ns. Such a pulse is inputted to a device whose characteristics are to be measured with a fine resolution of say <50 ps between sample points.

The requirement is to capture the waveform output from the test device with maximum signal integrity possible. The only known parameter is the input signal characteristics. So that's why I used the input signal's bandwidth and slew rate as the design consideration for selection of active device.

The waveform from the device/output from the black-box is of small amplitude for a  time duration and then ramps upto few mV. If I need to capture that few nv portions of the device characteristics some amplification has to be done to capture it in DSO and this brings the following couple of questions

- How can such a small voltage can be amplified to around few mV, keeping the bandwidth and slew rate into consideration?
- What sort of circuit design technique does one have to use for such cases? Is it with opamp/diffamp or what?

Comment: Define "capture" and "nV regime". If your experiment is at room temperature there are fundamental noise limits which may come into play.

Comment: Okay. say if one wants to see the output in a DSO,then he/she needs to amplify from nV to the minimum DSO displayable mV regime. This is at  room temperature but lets assume the measurement setup is maintained at constant controlled ambient temperature.

Comment: Just how accurately and how precisely do you need to measure this signal?

Comment: Its always better to capture the signal with the same rise time scales. But still a few 10s of ns tolerance is acceptable

Comment: 10s of nanoseconds would be a 30 MHz bandwidth, not 6 GHz.  It would be helpful if you  would define the exact bandwidth you want to amplify as well as the exact output you want.  Otherwise it is hard to know if this is even possible.

Comment: Resolution would be quite important in this… 1nV to 100µV is 5 decades, you would need a 16 bit (linear!) sampler to capture that. One of the reason for the cost of spectrum analyzers is the logarithmic amplifier on the input…

Comment: 1 nV into 50 Ohms is -137 dBm. I hate to say this, but hire an RF expert with extensive experience in low-noise techniques or just forget it. You are way, way out of the realm of op-amp circuits. Trying to sample or capture or characterize a -137 dBm signal with 6 GHz bandwidth is not going to be easy. If the signal is highly repeatable, your best bet may be to sample over and over again and use averaging to improve SNR. But it will still be hard.

Comment: You talk about a ludicrous requirement to 'capture such a large input variation **without compromising**' (hint, there are always compromises in electronics) from a 'blackbox' as some kind of hypothetical, then want to know what _specific_ components will be needed to do it? Do you have an actual application in mind?

Comment: _" The requirement is to capture the waveform output from the test device with **maximum** signal integrity **possible**."_- 'maximum possible' is not a specification. _"The waveform from the device/output from the black-box is of small amplitude for a time duration and then ramps upto few mV. **If I need to capture that few nv** portions of the device characteristics"_ - why might you need to do this?

Comment: The response from the device always has certain characteristics features embedded into it because of the influence of the device on the signal characteristics. If such is the case why should one want to loose those weak portion of the signal.

Comment: J-N noise of a 50 ohm source resistance at room temperature and 1GHz BW is about 30uV RMS or perhaps 200uVp-p. That's fundamental noise in the source based on physics which the electronics can only make worse.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Nyquist_noise